# Populate one custom adapter with two different arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have two arraylist(AL1 and AL2) of different size and different types. I want to display both the list in same List View.
Please some one guide me.

mainActivity:

```
ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<LifeHabit> habitList = new ArrayList<LifeHabit>();

actionLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.habit_list);
foodLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.food_list);

actionLV.setAdapter(new ActionListAdapter(habitList,"LogActivity"));
foodLV.setAdapter(new FoodListAdapter(foodList));
```

getView for FoodAdapter:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_list_item, null);
        TextView actionName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        actionName.setText(foodList.get(position));
return view;
```

getView of ActionAdapter:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_items, null);

        final TextView actionName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.action_name);

        try {
            actionName.setText(userHabits.get(position).getDisplayName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return view;
```

Comment: okay and what you have tried for that ... ? can u pls post code whatever u have done .. ?

Comment: I have used 2 listView and different adapters. But that is not what I want.

Comment: can u pls post code whatever u have done .. ?

Comment: It all depends on how you want to display it, but basically you should extend BaseAdapter and create one `List<Object>` field that will contain both Food and Action items. Then override `getItemViewType()` method of the adapter and add two separate view types for each item type. Refer to this question for further assistance : http://stackoverflow.com/q/20928528/2150044

Comment: Thank you all for help. I have solved the problem by converting both the list to string type.